# Implementing complex-valued matrix equation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am attempting to implement a complex-valued matrix equation in OpenCV. I've prototyped in MATLAB which works fine. Starting off with the equation (exact MATLAB implementation):

```
kernel = exp(1i .* k .* Circ3D) .* z ./ (1i .* lambda .* Circ3D .* Circ3D)
```

In which

```
1i = complex number
k = constant (float)
Circ3D = real-valued matrix of known size
lambda = constant (float)
.* = element-wise multiplication
./ = element-wise division
```

The result is a complex-valued matrix. I succeeded in generating the necessary Circ3D matrix as a CV_32F, however the multiplication by the complex number i is giving me trouble. From the OpenCV documentation I understand that a complex matrix is simply a two-channel matrix (CV_32FC2).

The real trouble comes from how to define i. I've tried several options, among which defining i as

```
cv::Vec2d complex = cv::Vec2d(0,1);
```

and then multiplying by the matrix

```
kernel = complex * Circ3D
```

But this doesn't work (although I didn't expect it to). I suspect I need to do something with std::complex but I have no idea what (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Just after writing this post I did make some progress, by defining i as follows:

```
std::complex<float> complex(0,1)
```

I am then able to assign complex values as follows:

```
kernel.at<std::complex<float>>(i,j) = cv::exp(complex * k * Circ3D.at<float>(i,j)) * ...
z / (complex * lambda * pow(Circ3D.at<float>(i,j),2));
```

However, this works in a loop, which makes the procedure incredibly slow. Any way to do it in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV treats `std::complex` just like the simple pair of numbers (see [example in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=complex)). No special rules on arithmetic operations are applied. You overcome this by multiplying `std::complex` directly. So basically, this is simple: you either chose automatic complex arithmetic (as you are doing now), or automatic vectorization (when using OpenCV functions on matrices).

I think, in your case you should carry all the complex arithmetic by yourself. Store matrix of complex values `C{ai + b}` as two matrices `A{a}` and `B{b}`. Implement exponentiation [by yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). Multiplication on scalars and addition shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ended up following your advise. Implemented the complex exponentiation using Euler's formula. This was extra easy since I know a priori that k and Circ3D are real so the equation needed only be rewritten once and implemented as such.

Comment: For future reference:

I've created a general cv::Mat complexMul(cv::Mat A, cv::Mat B) function that performs correct element-wise multiplication of complex matrices by splitting (cv::split) both matrices A = A1 + A2*i and B = B1 + B2*i into their real (A1, B1) and complex (A2, B2) parts and then calculating C = A.*B = (A1 + A2*i)(B1 + B2*i) by calculating C1 = (A1.*B1 - A2.*B2) and C2 = (A1.*B2 + A2.*B1) separately and using cv::merge to create C = C1 + C2*i. 

Note that i=sqrt(-1) and .* denotes element-wise multiplication.

Comment: Stackoverflow didn't let me put those tiny two comments into one as it became too long?! What is this, Twitter? ;)

Comment: I guess, you're doing it right. Glad my answer helped. Thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the function [mulSpectrums](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20mulSpectrums(InputArray%20a,%20InputArray%20b,%20OutputArray%20c,%20int%20flags,%20bool%20conjB)), which lets you do element wise multiplication of complex matrices. So if K is your kernel matrix and I is some complex matrix, that is, CV_32FC2 (float two channel) you can do the following to compute the element wise multiplication,

```
// Make K a complex matrix
cv::Mat Ktmp[] = {cv::Mat_<float>(K), cv::Mat::zeros(K.size(), CV_32FC1)};
cv::Mat Kc;
cv::merge(Ktmp,2,Kc);
// Do matrix multiplication
cv::mulSpectrums(Kc,I,I,0);
```

Comment: is there one for division?